# python pandas - editing axes tickmarks

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, multiple-axes

You can see the graph below which is from Jupyter. I'd like to edit the tick labels on x-axis which are currently a mess. This problem only occurs after I add the secondary axis. They represent years from 1922 to 2014. I'd like the graph to show only every 10th year. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the handle of your figure to access the axis. The following snippet will make you end up with a tick label every 10 years ..

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 ... ... plot your things
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base=10))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, using your code I get this: http://oi68.tinypic.com/24vpu0g.jpg. It removed the mess but left me with no tickmarks on the x axis :/

Comment: Interesting. For me it works like a charm. I'll look into this later... :/

Comment: EDIT: don't plot it from pandas frame, use `ax.plot` if you want to make use of this handle :)

Comment: (And make sure your x axis is actually comprised of years..if it is integer numbers, another Locator needs to be used)